# w3c validator and for (var i=0;i<lista.length;i++)

Tags: javascript, validation

i was optimizing [this webiste](http://toniweb.us/gm/) for ie7 and now just tested it on ie8 and it won't work as expected, first time that a later version gives me problem...

so i thought i will validate as long i can not get javascript errors in ie (can I?)

and it jumps few error in expresions like:

```
for (var i=0;i<lista.length;i++)
```

saying:

```
 Line 256, Column 32: character ";" not allowed in attribute specification list
```

Question is:

- should I ignore this error? or it could actually make the page crash?
- (do you have any idea how to debugg errors in IE7?)

Comment: this doesn't appear to be a jQuery question.

Comment: i was validating this file http://toniweb.us/gm/index.html @Joseph true, sorry..

Comment: Your `for` loop looks ok; however it will perform much faster if you cache the value of `lista.length`: `for (var i=0, len = lista.length; i < len; i++)`

Comment: It may be due to `<` character. Could you try put your scripts in `CDATA` tag?

Comment: IE has built-in developer tools including a JavaScript debugger.  You can also debug JavaScript in IE using Visual Studio or Visual Web Developer.

Comment: I ran it through the validator and got the same error on line 260 followed by:
`Line 260, Column 32: element "lista.length" undefined`
This indicates to me that the your lista array is not properly defined.
However, further down you get this error:
`Line 269, Column 10: end tag for "lista.length" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified </script>`
So maybe you should try closing the `</script>` tag properly

Answer (score 2):

You have specified the XHTML doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

In XHTML, you should put your JavaScript code in [CDATA sections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/properly_using_css_and_javascript_in_xhtml_documents#Using_CDATA_Instead_of_Comments), because the `<` character is being interpeted as the start of a tag.

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
...
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: if not, what doctype shall i declare?

Comment: "If not"? Do you want to use the HTML5 DOCTYPE? `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: i mean, if i canot use scripts that are not in cdata sections, the one i should try is <!DOCTYPE html> ??

Comment: The simpliest valid HTML5 syntax is: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title></head><body><script>...code, < is valid here...</script></body></html>`. Validate your HTML5 code at http://validator.w3.org/.

Comment: if i put this cdata tags: Line 16, Column 3: character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data

//<[CDATA[

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet There was a missing `!`. It should be `//<![CDATA[ ... //]]>`. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might check out jquery's each function:

```
$.each(lista, function(index, value) {
     // do what's in your for loop
});
```

Comment: jQuery is nice and easy but be aware that this performs much slower than a well written `for` loop: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops

Comment: @Jasper sure, but a million ops/sec in that test for the .each() still qualifies as 'immediate' under most circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the old days we had to do this:

```
<script>
<!--
   for(var i = 0; i < 0; i++) {}
-->
</script>
```

which would [**comment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Importance_of_Correct_Commenting) the JavaScript out of the html markup.

> The JavaScript language was specifically written to accept the start
>   of an HTML comment as the very first thing in the script and to ignore
>   it in order that the HTML comment could be used to hide the script
>   from people using Netscape 1, Mozaic, Internet Explorer 1, Internet
>   Explorer 2, and other browsers of similar vintage none of which anyone
>   uses any more. It is these prehistoric browsers (in JavaScript terms)
>   that are meant when you see references in antiquated JavaScript
>   tutorials to wrapping your JavaScript inside an HTML comment in order
>   to hide it from "older" browsers.